# Do rails model validations take priority?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In a model I have the following validations:

```
validates_presence_of :company_name, :message => "Must have a company name"
validates_uniqueness_of :company_name, :message => "Does this company exist? As this company name isn't unique."
```

Does this mean that it will check for the presence of the company name before its uniqueness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the rails guide: "validations will be run in the same order as they were registered."

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the check will be done sequentially

You can check it with:

```
if obj.errors.on(:company_name)
    errMsg << obj.errors.on(:company_name)[0]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will check presence first. It runs validations sequentially